# how do i move multipal balls

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how do i add multipel ball to move plss help
here is the code for ball and how it bounces
review it

i think its the obj name thats where the problem
i cant manage to make new name on evry time a new obj
is created

i also tried jquary to add multipal ball ellement
but that also does not work

```js
// code for ball
const INITIAL_VELOCITY = 0.085
const VELOCITY_CHANGE_RATE = 0
class Ball {
  constructor(ballElem) {
    this.ballElem = ballElem
    this.reset()
  }
  get x() {
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElem).getPropertyValue("--x"))
  }
  set x(value) {
    this.ballElem.style.setProperty("--x", value)
  }
  get y() {
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElem).getPropertyValue("--y"))
  }
  set y(value) {
    this.ballElem.style.setProperty("--y", value)
  }
  rect() {
    return this.ballElem.getBoundingClientRect()
  }
  reset() {
    this.x = 50
    this.y = 50
    this.direction = {x : 0}
    while (Math.abs(this.direction.x) <= 0.1 || Math.abs(this.direction.x) >= 0.9) {
      const heading = randomNumberBetween(0, 2 * Math.PI)
      this.direction = { x: Math.cos(heading), y: Math.sin(heading) }
    }
    this.velocity = INITIAL_VELOCITY
  }
update(delta,index) {
console.log(delta,index)
    this.x += this.direction.x * this.velocity * delta
    this.y += this.direction.y * this.velocity * delta
    // this.velocity += VELOCITY_CHANGE_RATE * delta
    // this.velocity -= VELOCITY_CHANGE_RATE / delta
    const rect = this.rect()

    if (rect.bottom >= window.innerHeight || rect.top <= 0) {
      this.direction.y *= -1
    }
    if (rect.right >= window.innerWidth || rect.left <= 0) {
      this.direction.x *= -1
    }

    //background color
    const hue = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--hue"));
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--hue", hue + delta * 0.02)
  }
}
function randomNumberBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}
var ballarr = []

for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML +=  `<div class="ball" id="ball${i}"></div>`

    ballarr[i] = new Ball(document.querySelector(`#ball${i}`))
}

console.log(ballarr)
// const ball = new Ball(document.querySelector("#ball"))

let lastTime
function updateTime(time) {
  if (lastTime != null) {
    const delta = time -  lastTime
    
   ballarr.map((val, index) => {
   val.update(delta, index)
   
   })
  }
  lastTime = time
  window.requestAnimationFrame(updateTime)
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :root {
  --hue: 200;
  --saturation: 50%;
  --foreground-color: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 75%);
  --background-color: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 20%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ball {
  --x: 50;
  --y: 50;
  position: absolute;
  /*background-color: var(--foreground-color); */
  /*background-color: #13ecb6;*/
  background-color: black;
  /*border: 4px solid #13ecb6;*/
  left: calc(var(--x) * 1vw);
  top: calc(var(--y) * 1vh);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 3vh;
  height: 3vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball" id="ball"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to how you create the balls and add them to the DOM and your `ballarr` array:

```
var ballarr = []
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  const ballEl = document.createElement('div');
  ballEl.classList.add('ball');
  document.body.appendChild(ballEl);
  const ball = new Ball(ballEl);
  ballarr.push(ball);
}
```

You also need to use `forEach()` to loop through the array to update ball positions, not `map()`:

```
ballarr.forEach(ball => ball.update(delta));
```

Here's a full working example:

```js
// code for ball
const INITIAL_VELOCITY = 0.085
const VELOCITY_CHANGE_RATE = 0

class Ball {
  constructor(ballElem) {
    this.ballElem = ballElem
    this.reset()
  }
  get x() {
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElem).getPropertyValue("--x"))
  }
  set x(value) {
    this.ballElem.style.setProperty("--x", value)
  }
  get y() {
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElem).getPropertyValue("--y"))
  }
  set y(value) {
    this.ballElem.style.setProperty("--y", value)
  }
  rect() {
    return this.ballElem.getBoundingClientRect()
  }
  reset() {
    this.x = 50
    this.y = 50
    this.direction = {
      x: 0
    }
    while (Math.abs(this.direction.x) <= 0.1 || Math.abs(this.direction.x) >= 0.9) {
      const heading = randomNumberBetween(0, 2 * Math.PI)
      this.direction = {
        x: Math.cos(heading),
        y: Math.sin(heading)
      }
    }
    this.velocity = INITIAL_VELOCITY
  }
  update(delta) {
    this.x += this.direction.x * this.velocity * delta
    this.y += this.direction.y * this.velocity * delta
    const rect = this.rect()

    if (rect.bottom >= window.innerHeight || rect.top <= 0) {
      this.direction.y *= -1
    }
    if (rect.right >= window.innerWidth || rect.left <= 0) {
      this.direction.x *= -1
    }

    //background color
    const hue = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--hue"));
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--hue", hue + delta * 0.02)
  }
}

function randomNumberBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}

var ballarr = []
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  const ballEl = document.createElement('div');
  ballEl.classList.add('ball');
  document.body.appendChild(ballEl);
  const ball = new Ball(ballEl);
  ballarr.push(ball);
}

let lastTime

function updateTime(time) {
  if (lastTime != null) {
    const delta = time - lastTime
    ballarr.forEach(ball => ball.update(delta));
  }
  lastTime = time
  window.requestAnimationFrame(updateTime)
}

updateTime(lastTime);
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :root {
  --hue: 200;
  --saturation: 50%;
  --foreground-color: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 75%);
  --background-color: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 20%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ball {
  --x: 50;
  --y: 50;
  position: absolute;
  /*background-color: var(--foreground-color); */
  /*background-color: #13ecb6;*/
  background-color: black;
  /*border: 4px solid #13ecb6;*/
  left: calc(var(--x) * 1vw);
  top: calc(var(--y) * 1vh);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 3vh;
  height: 3vh;
}
```

Comment: thank you and one more question how do i colide one ball with anathor

Comment: I'd suggest using an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for that